# Lando app that contains vue app and using proxy always come up with error 404

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, proxy, lando

I have vue app
usually I ran this on my local without containerization. when I ran `npm start`  it will running in `localhost:8080` without any error
and I move using lando. my `.lando.yml` file looks like this following code:

```
name: throne_fe
services:
  node: 
    type: node:14 
    config:
      portforward: 8080
    build: 
      - npm install
    command: npm start
    ssl: true
    depends_on:
      - python
  python: 
    type: python:2.7
tooling:  
    npm: 
      service: node
proxy:
  node:
    - throne_fe.lndo.site:8080
```

and when I ran `lando start`  its successfully running without any error (based on `lando logs`) but somehow it always return 404 when I visit `https://throne_fe.lndo.site/`
anyone can help me, whats wrong with my app?
please advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.lando.dev/core/v3/proxy.html#proxy-urls-create-404-error-in-firefox

Comment: But it happen in Chrome @RickRackow